# Adding watermarks to exports

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have several access databases that I export out of either in Excel or PDF.  Now I am told that i need to add watermark to all of my exports.  However, I am not sure if this is possible or if it can be done.  Do you know how I can add a watermark to a an export out of access saved as PDF or Excel file.

I created code to export to excel and email the file.  I also created an add-in in excel that inserts the watermark.  I dont know how to use together.

This is the code I am using to export to excel and email:

```
Function ExportDailyPayoffs()
    Dim dtemnyr As String
    Dim mondt As String

    If Weekday(Date) = vbMonday Then 'Check to see if its Monday
        dtemnyr = Format(Date - 3, "mmddyy") 'We want to get the file for Friday
    Else
        dtemnyr = Format(Date - 1, "mmddyy") 'We want to get the file for Friday
    End If

    DoCmd.SendObject acSendQuery, "A1 Daily Payoffs", acFormatXLSX, "CLSS@xxxx.US", , , "Daily Payoff Report - " & dtemnyr, "Enclosed please find the Daily Payoff Report", True
End Function
```

I want the word(watermark) CONFIDENTIAL to be in the excel when it gets exported out of access or email to anyone.

Comment: Therefore you would probably first need to save the export as Excel to your harddisk, then manipulate it (add the watermark) and then send it as email. With `DoCmd.SendObject` it will send it directly and you have no chance to manipulate the Excel file anymore, so you will need to use other techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a watermark to a .pdf output is straightforward. In design view, a report has a Picture property. That picture can be a watermark, created as a graphic file. The watermark is under all of the text, borders, etc., as if it's part of the paper on which the report is being printed, but to see the watermark properly you need to set the controls' background to transparent. If the watermark is a fairly unsaturated (pastel) color, then the text will be quite readable over the watermark.

Adding a watermark to Excel output is harder. I know of no way to do it directly within Access. I recently needed to do something similar, reformatting Excel output to modify column widths, let selected columns' contents wrap, and so on. I did it by writing an Excel workbook to do the reformatting of the exported workbook. Immediately after I export a workbook, the VBA code which exports it then opens the reformatting workbook, which auto-executes to perform its work and then closes itself. This isn't the right place to explain all of the details, but that's the general approach.